# Full-text indexing vs %% and clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, full-text-search, clustered-index

I have two questions.

1. Does it make sense when I have to choice of a clustered index on an `Integer` type column instead of choosing it over string values type column.

Why?

*The clustered index will cause a reordering of the page data whenever an INSERT is processed because the new row is not appended to the end of the index but inserted in the middle*

I am right? Any other reason for Choosing the clustered Index for `Integer` type column? Or I am moving in wrong direction?

1. When I have to search a string using `%...%` like below query

   ```
   Select Column1 From Table1 Where Column1 Like '%SomeVal%'
   ```

I have following questions for this.

1. Does it make sense to use `%....%` in the above situation?
2. Can I put the clustered index for `Column1` and then go for `%....%`
3. Should I choose full-text indexing? If so why I should prefer full-text indexing over `%...%` ?

Comment: prefix with '%' will do an index scan at best. Your questions don't really make sense. Rather than tell us your perceived solution, tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @mitchwheat - sir, my query is based upon contains predicate. As mentioned in the query.

Comment: I typically cluster my indexes on the most-utilized foreign key in the table, that way lookups/joins via that FK are in the same page on disk (should be faster).  Also, %...% are fairly expensive, depending on how many records you anticipate.  I'd avoid these whenever possible, but FTS is another can of worms.  As mentioned above, more details would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, SQL Server (and computers in general) are faster at looking through lists of numbers than they are through lists of text. That means that it's generally faster to search for a record WHERE ID = 3 than WHERE FirstName = 'BOB'. That works great if you're system is geared up to track one or the other, like when the user clicks on a product you can choose to store the ProductID or the ProductName, the ProductID will pull faster. However, if the only column that's going to be in that WHERE clause is a text filed, like you're always looking for a movie by its title, then you're probably better off putting your clustered index on that column. As a general rule I have an integer ID field with the clustered index and then put a nonclustered index on the other field, but it really depends on the situation.
2. FTS is word-based while wildcards (%) are pattern-based, so if you need to search a text field for "Patricia", FTS would probably be your best choice, but if you needed to search for "Pat%" to look for "Patrick" or "Pattie" or "Patricia", FTS will not work well. I hope that makes sense. Search StackOverflow or [google](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=fts%20vs%20like) for "fts vs like" and you'll get a few discussions on the matter.